# Unable to create tables using spring data jpa in mysql

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

Spring JPA does not create the tables under the schema or MySql db.

```
#DataSource
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/pickalystoredatabase?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root

# Keep the connection alive if idle for a long time (needed in production)
spring.datasource.testWhileIdle = true
spring.datasource.validationQuery = SELECT 1

# Show or not log for each sql query
spring.jpa.show-sql = true

# Hibernate ddl auto (create, create-drop, update)
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update

# Naming strategy
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming-strategy = org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy

# Use spring.jpa.properties.* for Hibernate native properties (the prefix is
# stripped before adding them to the entity manager)

# The SQL dialect makes Hibernate generate better SQL for the chosen database
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
```

The application properties seem to be perfect. I also do not see any errors in the logs

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private Long id;
    @Column(name = "username", nullable = false)
    private String username;
    @Column(name = "password", nullable = false)
    private String password;
    @Column(name = "firstname", nullable = false)
    private String firstname;
    @Column(name = "lastname", nullable = false)
    private String lastname;

    @Column(name = "email", nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private String email;
    @Column(name = "phone", nullable = false)
    private String phone;
    @Column(name = "enabled", nullable = false)
    private boolean enabled = true;

    public User() { }
    //getters snad setters
}
```

I am using the spring-boot-started-data-jpa maven dependency. Version 1.5.9 RC.

Logs for your reference

The logs does not show any exception and it also does not have any information with respect to the creation of tables.

```
2018-01-31 00:18:53.662  INFO 6640 
--- [  restartedMain] com.pickaly.application.Pickaly          : Starting Pickaly on PHYADAVI-6Q4D5 with PID 6640 (C:\Users\phyadavi\pickaly\Pickaly-Store\target\classes started by phyadavi in C:\Users\phyadavi\pickaly\Pickaly-Store) 2018-01-31 00:18:53.662  INFO 6640 
--- [  restartedMain] com.pickaly.application.Pickaly          : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default 2018-01-31 00:18:53.664  INFO 6640 
--- [  restartedMain] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@5db9f92a: startup date [Wed Jan 31 00:18:53 IST 2018]; root of context hierarchy 2018-01-31 00:18:54.243  INFO 6640 
--- [  restartedMain] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http) 2018-01-31 00:18:54.244  INFO 6640 
--- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat] 2018-01-31 00:18:54.244  INFO 6640 
--- [  restartedMain] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.23 2018-01-31 00:18:54.269  INFO 6640 
--- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext 2018-01-31 00:18:54.270  INFO 6640 
--- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 606 ms 2018-01-31 00:18:54.302  INFO 6640
--- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean  : Mapping servlet: 'dispatcherServlet' to [/] 2018-01-31 00:18:54.302  INFO 6640 
--- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*] 2018-01-31 00:18:54.302  INFO 6640
--- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*] 2018-01-31 00:18:54.302  INFO 6640
--- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'httpPutFormContentFilter' to: [/*] 2018-01-31 00:18:54.302  INFO 6640 
--- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*] 2018-01-31 00:18:54.443  INFO 6640 
--- [  restartedMain] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default' 2018-01-31 00:18:54.443  INFO 6640 
--- [  restartedMain] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [    name: default   ...] 2018-01-31 00:18:54.460  INFO 6640 
--- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect          : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect 2018-01-31 00:18:54.467  INFO 6640 
--- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate  : HHH000228: Running hbm2ddl schema update 2018-01-31 00:18:54.468  INFO 6640 
--- [  restartedMain] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default' 2018-01-31 00:18:54.553  INFO 6640 
--- [  restartedMain] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter : Looking for @ControllerAdvice: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@5db9f92a: startup date [Wed Jan 31 00:18:53 IST 2018]; root of context hierarchy 2018-01-31 00:18:54.564  INFO 6640 
--- [  restartedMain] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/]}" onto public java.lang.String com.pickaly.controllers.HomeController.index() 2018-01-31 00:18:54.567  INFO 6640 
--- [  restartedMain] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.error(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest) 2018-01-31 00:18:54.567  INFO 6640 
--- [  restartedMain] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error],produces=[text/html]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.errorHtml(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse) 2018-01-31 00:18:54.574  INFO 6640 
--- [  restartedMain] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/webjars/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler] 2018-01-31 00:18:54.575  INFO 6640 
--- [  restartedMain] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler] 2018-01-31 00:18:54.587  INFO 6640 
--- [  restartedMain] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**/favicon.ico] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler] 2018-01-31 00:18:54.661  INFO 6640 
--- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.a.OptionalLiveReloadServer       : LiveReload server is running on port 35729 2018-01-31 00:18:54.705  INFO 6640 
--- [  restartedMain] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup 2018-01-31 00:18:54.718  INFO 6640
--- [  restartedMain] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) 2018-01-31 00:18:54.720  INFO 6640 
--- [  restartedMain] com.pickaly.application.Pickaly          : Started Pickaly in 1.098 seconds (JVM running for 720.446)
```

Please help.

Edit:

In addition to the above mentioned properties i also used properties and annotations like

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EntityScan(basePackages = {"com.pickaly.domains"})

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect instead of MySQLDBDialect
```

But these configurations did not work.

Comment: Please format logs as code. It's almost impossible to parse like this.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `spring.jpa.generate-ddl =  true` to your application properties.